# Buscar en JTable con capas

Tags: sql-server, java-8, netbeans-8.2

Estoy intentando de realizar mi método buscar en un Jtable, pero no me esta funcionando no me da error, pero tampoco me realiza la búsqueda, esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

***EDITE la pregunta con la sintaxis de SQL y JAVA, en SQL si me funciona correctamente, pero no en JAVA, tampoco me arroja error.***

En mi capa de acceso a datos, agregue una variable buscar misma que agregue en la linea de SQL:

```
    public void buscarEmpleado(Connection con, JTable tabla, String buscar){
    DefaultTableModel model;
    String[] columnas = {"ID", "NOMBRE","APELLIDO","CEDULA","ESTADO CIVL","GENERO", "EDAD"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnas);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLEADO WHERE ID LIKE '%"+buscar+"' OR NOMBRE LIKE '%"+buscar+"%' ORDER BY idEmpleado";
    
    String [] filas = new String[7];
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    
    try 
    {
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()){
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                filas[i] = rs.getString(i+1);
            }
            model.addRow(filas);
        }
        tabla.setModel(model);
    } catch (SQLException e) 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se puede mostrar la tabla");
    }
   
}
```

En mi capa de negocio, agregue también mi método correspondiente:

```
public void buscarEmpleado(JTable tabla, String buscar){
    Connection conn = Conexion.getConnection();
    edao.buscarEmpleado(conn, tabla, buscar);
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y en en panel donde quiero hacer la llamo al método de mi capa de negocio

```
public pnlSearch() {
    initComponents();
    listarEmpleado();
    buscarEmpleado();           
}
   
public void buscarEmpleado(){
ebo.buscarEmpleado(tblEmp, "AQUI QUE VA?");
}

private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    
    buscarEmpleado();
}
```

EDICIÓN:

```
***--SQL
```

SELECT * FROM EMPLEADO WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%E%' ORDER BY idEmpleado
--JAVA
SELECT * FROM EMPLEADO WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '%"+buscar+"%' ORDER BY idEmpleado***

Que puede estar mal, repito no me devuelve error pero tampoco me realiza la búsqueda?

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda que puedan darme.

DS

Comment: Saludos. Mmmm... lo primero es que revises si la consulta que usas con el dato(s) que proporcionas de entrada devuelve algo. Es decir probar el `SELECT` (digamos) en SQL Server Management Studio pruebes en el `WHERE`del `ID` se entiende como un **Termine con** y del `NOMBRE` como **contenga**. Espero te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por contestar, el where ID lo agregue en última instancia, el where nombre en el SQL si me funciona pero no en la aplicación @RobertoLeOr

Comment: @RobertoLeOr
Edute la pregunta con la consulta correcta en SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado de esta forma en mi JFrame tenia mal esta linea de código:

```
public void buscarEmpleado(){
ebo.buscarEmpleado(tblEmp,txtSearch.getText());
}

  private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    buscarEmpleado();
}
```

Gracias de antemano!!!!